Encoding and decoding J1939 Messages
I am working on a J1939 stack and intend for it to function as an ECU that sends sensor values as messages to other ECUs. I would appreciate guidance on the following:
Encoding J1939 Messages: What are the standard procedures or methods for encoding messages in the J1939 protocol?
Standard Files for Encoding: Are there standardized files, similar to the DBC files used for decoding, that can be utilized for encoding J1939 messages?
Any assistance or resources on this matter would be highly appreciated.
